# Как передавать аргументы в native методы

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, jni

Возникла проблема с передачей аргументов в методы, реализованные в нативном коде (JNI,NDK Android). Основное ядро использует С - функции. Данные функции должны принимать аргументы (int,string,float,boolean), но при попытке отправить аргумент в функцию (вызов метода в основном java коде), в нативном коде я его не получаю, вообще сначала я что то делал, и вместо моего числа вылетало 98488943 ~ что то похожее. Теперь же, вообще крашится приложение при попытке вызвать нативный метод с аргументом. Боевой пример:

```
  void Java_ivsystems_sqliteadapter_MainActivity_TestArgument( JNIEnv* env,
jobject thiz, jint jn){
 LOGE(jn);
}
```

Собственно, пытаюсь в нативную функцию передать целое число. В вызывающем коде

```
 ... какой то код ...
 TestArgument(200);
       }

    public native void TestArgument(int jn);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
```

И приложение просто падает (A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc8 in tid 32404 (s.sqliteadapter))
Я так думаю, нужно или выделять память, или что то еще? Кто сможет, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Разобрался. Просто очень мало опыта работы с NDK.

Comment: Напишите ответ на свой же вопрос, пригодится кому-нибудь.